# catch does not get activated when pdo connect gets an error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

trying to connect to a database remotely. There is a ip filter of who can. whenever a user who cant connect the error is displayed in the page and everything after the error stops working. Im trying to pass the error into a variable (with try catch and other methods) but nothing happens. the catch part is like getting ignored.

I tried all mysqli_report flags

How do i make sure the user does not get an error if the this happens? I need the error message to be loading into a variable so i could load the error message whenever i wish wherever i wish instead of it throwing an error and shutting down the operation.

Also just noticed that the error shows the user the password, host and username login details to database. So it is important to disable it

**UPDATE:**

current code does not work still

```
try {
    $conn = new \PDO(
        "mysql:host=$hostname_db;dbname=myDB",
        $username_db, $password_db,
        [\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
    );
} 
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $err = $e->getMessage();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $err = $e->getMessage();
}
```

The error that is displayed (most of it):

[image]

Comment: The only reason I can think of is linked above

Comment: worked perfectly! Thank you. I did not even notice i missed the \

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the options directly while creating the instance. Use `\` to be sure using the correct namespace.

```php
try {
    $conn = new \PDO(
        "mysql:host=$hostname_db;dbname=myDB",
        $username_db, $password_db,
        [\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
    );

    echo "Connected successfully";
} 
catch(\PDOException $e)
{
    $err = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Did not work. The user still receives and error, the entire page stops processing and, just now noticed, it even displays login details to database (password, host, username).

Comment: Please see answer updated. You need to set the attributes directly on creating the new instance. Setting it later, is too late.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not too late

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this did not work either. I attached a photo of what a user (whos ip is not apart of allowed access list) recieves.

Comment: Your answer is not helpful as it is based on the wrong premise, no matter what the question is

Comment: Sorry, but the downvote was not me.

Comment: Try put a slash before exception type. Maybe it is a namespace problem `catch(\PDOException $e)` or `catch(\PDO::PDOException $e)`.

Comment: yeah, worked perfectly. forgot to add a \. Thank you all for helping!

Comment: Answer is updated. You're welcome.